# Entity GUID is overwritten when manually populated

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

[image: My Entity]

I am populating my context for my tests. but for  some reason my Guids gets overwritten upon creation of the entity.
I think there is something wrong on my context setup, but I am below average when it comes to entity framework setups.

Edit:

Seed Code:

```
    try
            {
                using (var context = this.GetContext())
                {
                    context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                    context.Database.EnsureCreated();



                    var lets = new Entities.Models.Users()
                    {
                        Id = Guid.Parse("3859e4c1-aaf7-4d9b-bc5e-8730ae9ad531"),
                        Name = "Test Pilot",
                        Organization = new Entities.Models.Organizations
                        {
                            Id = 12312
                        },
                        AppRoles = new Entities.Models.UserRequestRoles
                        {
                            AppRole = ""
                        }
                    };
                    context.Users.Add(lets);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
```

User Entity:

```
     public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        // User Details
        public string GivenName { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }
        public virtual Organizations Organization { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public virtual UserRequestRoles AppRoles { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual IEnumerable<UserOrganizations> UserOrganizations { get; set; }
}
```

Context builder:

```
        builder.Entity<Users>(a =>
        {
            a.HasKey(a => a.Id);
            a.HasOne(b => b.Organization)
            .WithMany(b => b.Users);
            a.HasMany<UserOrganizations>(c => c.UserOrganizations);
            a.HasOne(b => b.AppRoles);
        });
```

There are no errors. its just populating my context.
Any idea why is this happening, thank you

Comment: please include code, error messages, and other _text-based_ information ***as text***, not as screenshot.

Comment: Its really hard to understand whats happening here please include the code. I assume whats happening is that you give the object an id that is all ready taken, and the database gives the entry a new id that is not taken.

Comment: I guess the Id that he gets is not equal to the one he sets

Comment: Okay.. yes I think the screenshot was bad, but if you may, 
on the screen shot, the values shown are right after I assigned it to the variable(lets).

Comment: @FranzGleichmann This is one of those cases where an image is better than a snippet of code.

Comment: @Jolo It's ok brother, that is a a very good image that tells a lot of useful information. Don't worry. (btw, Check my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why is this happening

It's happening because **you instructed EF to automatically populate the value of that column** via the `.HasKey()` extension method. Remove the call to that method - you've already specified that the column is a key column with the `[Key]` attribute defined on it, there's no need to tell EF twice.

In your test, you then need to [configure your entity so that it ignores the `[Key]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#overriding-value-generation):

```
builder.Entity<Users>(a =>
{
    a.HasOne(b => b.Organization)
        .WithMany(b => b.Users);
    a.HasMany<UserOrganizations>(c => c.UserOrganizations);
    a.HasOne(b => b.AppRoles);
}).Property(user => user.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
    .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Save);
```